# UWP calendar view visible date range

Tags: range, controls, win-universal-app, visible, calendarview

I would like to know how to get the range of dates the user is able to see on the Universal Windows Platform CalendarView control. I already tried looking on the Microsoft website but i can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** By default, the minimum date shown in the [CalendarView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.aspx) is 100 years prior to the current date, and the maximum date shown is 100 years past the current date.

You can change the minimum and maximum dates that the calendar shows by setting the [MinDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.mindate.aspx) and [MaxDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.maxdate.aspx) properties. For example like this:

```cs
calendarView.MinDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
calendarView.MaxDate = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31);
```

You can also get the range of dates like this:

```cs
var minDate = calendarView.MinDate;
var maxDate = calendarView.MaxDate;
```

**2.** If what you want to do is changing the visible region of the `CalendarView` (by default it starts with the month view open, it shows 6 rows of dates which contain the current month.), you can use [CalendarView.SetDisplayDate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.setdisplaydate.aspx) for example like this:

```cs
DateTime localTime = new DateTime(2007, 07, 12, 06, 32, 00);
DateTimeOffset dateAndOffset = new DateTimeOffset(localTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(localTime));
calendarView.SetDisplayDate(dateAndOffset);
```

In this sample, the `CalendarView` will show the month 2007/7.

**3.** As I said, by default the number of weeks shown in the calendar view is 6, you can change it by [CalendarView.NumberOfWeeksInView property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.numberofweeksinview.aspx), for example in xaml code:

```
<CalendarView x:Name="calendarView" NumberOfWeeksInView="8" />
```

Or code behind:

```cs
calendarView.NumberOfWeeksInView = 8;
```

The minimum number of weeks to show is 2, the maximum is 8;

**4.** Besides the month view, there are also year view and decade view in `CalendarView`, you can change it with [CalendarView.DisplayMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.displaymode.aspx) for example in xaml code:

```
<CalendarView x:Name="calendarView" DisplayMode="Year"/>
```

Or in code behind:

```cs
calendarView.DisplayMode = CalendarViewDisplayMode.Decade;
```

Since you asked a quite simple but broad question, I list every possibilities I could think about. If you have any other questions about this control, please check [CalendarView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.aspx) again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , my question might indeed have been broad sorry, what i actually meant was: The user scrolls , navigates or w/e through the calendar , how is it possible for me to know which days ( date range ) are displayed on the calendar at a point in time. You see this is my exact problem , once the user starts navigating , i have no clue how to know what he is exactly seeing at that point. The reason i want to to this is because i want to load data from an API based on the dates being displayed: For example:

Comment: User scrolls ; 30/03 appears on the calendarview => load data for 30/03 from API. The thing is , I got something close to work by using the CalendarViewDayItemChanged event , but for some reasons it loads random dates when the control is created , so i'm making useless api calls because of it

Comment: @NicolasL, there is a event `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` which will get fired when user scroll this control, but it is triggered for every day items, this will make your loading data work very heavy. For your scenario, I think it's better to use `SelectedDatesChanged` event, when user select a day, load the data for that day.

Comment: well as i said in my earlier comment, i did try the calendarviewdayitemchanging event, the loading data being heavy won't be that much of a problem since i load it by month eventually but the problem is the event loading random dates from years ago  at start. I did think about the selecteddateschanged but i need it to navigate to a detail page unfortunately :( in the end i ended up having a separate datepicker control to load stuff by month so that'll have to do for now , thanks though :)

Comment: @NicolasL I hope you are still interested in this. In order to avoid the loading of random old dates from the control, you should bind its `MinDate`  to one suitable to your scenario. It worked for me. Also if you want to load your data and not mess with the controls usability(no lag and such) use the phase rendering capability as described  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/calendar-view?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).